# "Security signature is not present" in opensuse

Tags: opensuse

I am using open SUSE 11.4 in my computer. I recently installed this. I also did an online update. After which the following message keeps popping out from the bottom panel.

**A security signature is not present**

A security trust relationship could not be made with software source. Please check your security settings.
**More details**

Signature verification for Repository Google-Chrome64 failed

Can someone explain what this is and whether it is important to solve this issue or just to ignore?

Answer (score 0):

Its download happens from the google, from an unofficial google repository.

In the repositories the packages are signed with a security certificate, to assure, that nobody can be alter them.

The security cert is a tricky thing. It is practically a very long number created by complex algorithms. Its main feature, that only the SuSE can create a such certificate for a file, but anybody can test, if it is valid.

For example, a hacker could inject a spysoftware into the google chrome, either on the system of the google, or on its way to your system. It will be impossible, if the altered packages won't have a valid security certification.

Thus, there is 2 possible situation:

a) Google didn't created this security cert. On inofficial debian repositories is it also a common phenomenon.

b) Somehow were your chrome altered.

I said at least 99% to "a", especially if the download happened through a "https" connection. Although I never suggested to always ignore such warnings.

Maybe google hat produced his own certificate only for his suse package repository. In this case you can find this key and import into your system.